# How can I open a web-page from my applet?

Tags: java, swing

I have to open a page from class extended from javax.swing.AbstractAction class... Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(url,"_blank");
```

The interface AppletContext has the [method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Nope, pretty much sure that's it. Any reason why that won't work?